# UIButton doesn't stay in same place on top of UIImageView when changing orientation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, xcode7

Using Xcode7, I have a UIImageView with a fixed aspect ratio.  On top of this is a UIButton, constrained to the centre of the UIImageView, plus an x&y offset.  All is well until I change orientation; the button does not wind up in the same place on the image.

I must be making some painfully rookie mistake -- help!

Comment: code and/or pics of storyboard would be helpful to help you.

Comment: Are you getting any build warnings about the constraints associated with the button or the view?